# DolphinDB: How to access data from the same source but stored in different databases?

Tags: primary-key, database-partitioning, dolphindb

I have a data source RiceQuant and I want to specify different partition schemes for the same data source.

- daily data: partitioned by year
- minute-level data: partitioned by year/month and stock
- level-2 data: partitioned by date and stock

Now I create separate databases for each scenario. But this will lead to some databases containing only one table, making querying inconvenient. So I’m wondering if DolphinDB supports using views to reference data from multiple databases.

Furthermore, I’m curious whether I can create tables with indexed columns in the partitioned databases, similar to MySQL's normal tables.

I would greatly appreciate any insights and guidance from anyone who has dealt with similar situations. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access data from the same source but stored in different databases, you can define a function view that encapsulates the custom method to recognize the database prefixes and access the appropriate database for the required data.

The TSDB-engine in DolphinDB provides sort columns, which are not equivalent to MySQL indexes. For more detailed information, please refer to https://github.com/dolphindb/Tutorials_EN/blob/master/tsdb_engine.md#23-sort-columns